# Персональная ссылка на скачивание

Tags: php

Как сделать персональную ссылку на скачивание файла, для определенного пользователя, чтобы только он мог ею пользоваться.

Comment: Чего вы хотите этим добиться?

Comment: .  

                                 —————————————
    ————————> | Связанные вопросы |
                                 —————————————

Comment: @ReinRaus, игра не сто́ит свеч, я ж не зря задал вопрос в самом начале. Вы даете скачаивть какой-то файл одному человеку, который, например, оплатил данное скачивание. Но завтра, этот же человек, выкладывает этот файл на каком-нибудь файлообменнике абсолютно бесплатно. FALSE.

Comment: Ну если продается уникальный файл, к примеру какой-будь код активации

Comment: очень просто, не давай юзеру прямую ссылку, сделай файл который просто принимает гет[ид] - это будет id файла. в бд создай таблицу с полями (id|ip|id_file) там просто, сделай запрос в бд, вытащить * где ip = текущему ip и id файла = id_file .Перед этим запросом сначала проверь есть ли такой файл в бд, точнее файл с таким id, если ip в бд совпадает с текущем ip, то давай юзеру файл

Comment: @Алексей Скляр, угу... Всё бы хорошо, но что прикажите делать с теми, у кого динамический IP?

Comment: @Deonis а что IP меняется во время сессии? предполагается, что пользователь получит ссылку, и сразу перейдёт по ней

Comment: @Deonis то есть открыть ссылку всем?)

Comment: > предыдущий коммент

@Алексей Скляр, Тогда и IP не нужен

-----------------------------

> то есть открыть ссылку всем?)

@Алексей Скляр, а вы знаете, что на одном IP может сидеть сотни юзеров?

Answer (score 1):

Можно выделить несколько видов таких ссылок:

1. Авторизация доступа. Предполагается, что у пользователя уже есть аккаунт и при открытии ссылки мы заставляем его пройти аутентификацию чтобы проверить права. Сам URL это не секрет.
2. "Секретный адрес", по которому доступ будет иметь любой кто его знает. Скрипт, который его создаёт, может зарегистрировать этот адрес на имя пользователя, но фактически никак нельзя проверить тот ли пользователь ей воспользовался. И вероятно ей могут воспользоваться несколько пользователей.
3. То же, что и п.2, но ограниченный по числу использований и/или времени жизни.

Так что возможны варианты "как сделать" в зависимости от важности ресурса и уровня паранойи. Собственно отдача файла по ссылке это не проблема: складируем за пределами `DocumentRoot`, скриптом читаем и отдаём:

```
$key = $_GET['key'];
// ... опционально проверка прав и актуальности ссылки ...
$fileDescriptor = $fileModel->findByKey($key);
if ($fileDescriptor->location) {
  header("Content-type: {$fileDescriptor->mime}");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$fileDescriptor->filename}");
  readfile(FILE_ROOT . $fileDescriptor->location);
  // ... опционально удаление записи о файле ...
} else {
  header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем, если не учитывать то, что я описывал во втором своем комментарии и естественно не особо полагаясь на IP пользователя, то можно сделать следующим образом:

- В БД создаете таблицу, где храните ID пользователя (поле **`uid`**), **`file_name`** - поле с именем файла, статус **`status`** (0 - не оплачено, 1 - оплачено) и поле **`hash_file`**, где храните что-нибудь в роде **md5($file_name.$uid)**. Шифруете как считаете нужным: с солью или без, md5 или sha1, можно и XOR.
- Ссылку на скачивание, пользователь получает после того, как залогинился на вашем сайте и имеет статус "1" (оплачено).
- В то же время, как ему выдана ссылка, устанавливаете ему cookie с тем же хэшем, который и хранится в базе. **НО!!!** ... *читаем в самом конце*
- Естественно, что файл отдается только после того, как сравнение "хэша из кукисов" и "хэша из БД"  == true.
- Теперь по поводу "**НО**". Куки - не самый надежный способ, поэтому не помешает сделать некоторый комплекс. Например, **cookie** + **local storage**. Ну, и конечно радикальная мера в виде **[Evercookie](http://habrahabr.ru/post/104725/)**, которым надо пользоваться в крайних случаях и осторожненько, если вы уважаете своих посетителей, но об этом вы [прочитаете в той же статье](http://habrahabr.ru/post/104725/).

Всё равно, я считаю, что тратить на это большие силы смысла нет, но описанный выше способ, поможет хоть как-то контролировать раздачу файлов/информации и т.д. Кстати, не забудьте оповещать пользователя, что скачивание возможно только с его компьютера. Кроме того, можно сделать срок хранения хэша, о чем пользователь должен быть так же проинформирован. После истечения этого срока - хэш удаляете и БД.